# Variable Declaration in Store Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How many output variables can we define in a stored proc?

Because when I declared about 8 variables to hold the output, it shows error
like

> Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Comment: [Parameters per stored procedure: 2100](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#Engine)

Comment: can you add your stored procedure and passing parameters, b'cos you may be pass more parameters

Comment: Add the problem code to your question. The error suggests a mismatch in the number of parameters passed to a proc or function, not that you are exceeding a capacity limit (2100 parameters). Also, variables are not parameters.

Comment: Sorry guys for the delay.. I got the answer, there was some extra parameter issue in the code..
 Thank you so much for supporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

This usually happens if you make a stored procedure call with more number of parameters than it accepts. for example, if you have below stored procedure..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployees   
    @LastName nvarchar(50),   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)   
AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Department  
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment  
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName;  
GO
```

And from your c# or some other application code, if you pass 3 parameters `@LastName`, `@FirstName`, `@Address` then it fails with above error.